# count time of button click in 1 minute

Tags: asp.net

i use asp.net and ajax

I have a button and I want to count that, how many times was the button clicked in 1 minute.
if the user clicked the button more than 5 times in 1 minute it will be deny  for 5 minute. what is the best solution.?

Comment: Is this some type of Log In fail prevention?

Answer (score 1):

Store the times for each button-click (DateTime.Now) in a hidden value or somewhere you prefer (be it a database, an XML-file or whatever else). Then, every time the button is clicked, get the 1-5 latest click-times and see if they are within the last minute. From there on, you can deny access, set database-flags or do whatever you like.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is some reading about DateTime.

Comment: I press F5 and can login/save, whatever again.

Comment: I think for a timer(60 seconds) that start with as first click. while it counts down a counter  count times of button click. and I think to write it with js. but codes in client side can be edited. and they are not trustworthy. is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to store the datetimes that the user has clicked the button in a [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)-object. That way, the user can not change the value unless he restarts the browser.